# Как на javascript сделать древовидную структуру массива из массива из трёх полей id, name, parent?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, если я имею массив подобного вида и на сервере хранится в подобной структуре

```
[
  id:1,name:"Text",parent:0,
  id:2,name: "Folder in Parent Folder with id 1", parent: 1,
  id:555, name: "Rekursive folder in Folder 2....", parent:2
]
```

Я бы хотел в списке отрисовать эти данные, полученные данные отрисовать из массива, где parent это родительский элемент.

```
[
 id:1, name:"Text",
 children: [
   id:2,name: "Folder in Parent Folder with id 1", 
   children: [
     id:555, name: "Rekursive folder in Folder 2...."
   ]
]
```

Как это преобразовать рекурсивно, так как неизвестен уровень вложений?

Comment: Это все замечательно, вот только как вы различаете родителей если различные уровни вложенности?

Comment: У вас структура на сервере такая или ещё что-то?

Comment: @"Aziz Umarov" я пока что структуру на сервере не писал, но планирую такую делать(или Вы знаете вариант лучше?). Я хочу рекурсивно пройтись по массиву и как-то из массива из 3х полей сделать вложенный массив, что б потом в  Angular-е отрисовать список

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/z5bgLmt3/ - на любую вложенность

Answer (score 1):

Делается просто.

1. m1 = Мар(id, object) - мап всех элементов массива. Вам нужно хранить ссылки всех объектов в развернутом виде.
2. Пробегаете по исходному массиву находите  по id парента объект в m1 добавляете дочку в него. сам объект добавляете в m1 предварительно преобразовав (+ children: []).
3. Выбираете только те у которых парент 0

Answer (score 0):

```
const data=[
  {id:1,name:"Text",parent:0},
  {id:2,name: "Folder in Parent Folder with id 1", parent: 1},
  {id:555, name: "Rekursive folder in Folder 2....", parent:2}
]

const dataObj = data.reduce((acc,item)=>{
  acc[item.id]={
    id:item.id,
    name:item.name,
    children:[]
  }
  return acc
},{});

const result = data.reduce((acc,item)=>{
  if(item.parent===0) acc.push(dataObj[item.id])
  else if(dataObj[item.parent] && dataObj[item.id]) dataObj[item.parent].children.push(dataObj[item.id]);
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```